# How could i use a custom cursor from codepen with js import code to Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

i.e.

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="hero">

  </div>
</div>
```

```
import { neonCursor } from 'https://unpkg.com/threejs-toys@0.0.8/build/threejs-toys.module.cdn.min.js'

neonCursor({
  el: document.getElementById('app'),
  shaderPoints: 16,
  curvePoints: 80,
  curveLerp: 0.5,
  radius1: 5,
  radius2: 30,
  velocityTreshold: 10,
  sleepRadiusX: 100,
  sleepRadiusY: 100,
  sleepTimeCoefX: 0.0025,
  sleepTimeCoefY: 0.0025
})
```

It's a neon cursor effect and it seems like css is not needed. The original site is: https://codepen.io/soju22/pen/wvyBorP

but I can't add it to my website.  I want to make it run on my site.
Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.